# How to add the classpath with the new gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

I have a new project started with a template.
The project `build.gradle` file has a different format:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.44' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.8.10' apply false
}
```

and the `settings.gradle` contains:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "name"
...
```

I need to add the [Shot library](https://github.com/pedrovgs/Shot). The documentation states that I need to add:

```
  buildscript {
    // ...
    dependencies {
      // ...
      classpath 'com.karumi:shot:<LATEST_RELEASE>'
    }
  }
```

in the root `build.gradle`

How do I add it?

Comment: There is a special Android version of `shot`, have you tried to use it, e.g. `implementation 'com.karumi:shot-android:5.14.1'`  See all com.karumi libraries available on Maven repositories: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.karumi

Comment: @Robert thank you for your comment. My question is more basic. How can add the classpath dependency with the new gradle file?

Comment: Place the line I have posted in the apps `build.gradle` `dependencies` section?
https://developer.android.com/build/dependencies

Comment: but that doesn't work if you don't add the `classpath 'com.karumi:shot:<LATEST_RELEASE>'` first right?

Comment: that's not correct `classpath 'com.karumi:shot:<LATEST_RELEASE>'` is what you put in the root build.gradle the "project" build.gradle. The problem is that with the new template I get a build.gradle that is different

Comment: @1048576 Any solution to this? to add to the top level gradle file in the plugins{}